# Converting R code to Markdown or RNotebok

Tags: r

Hi I'm asked to do an assignment, which requests to submit RNotebook (or Markdown) as html files for grading. This is a machine learning assignment.
What I need to know it, I'm going to use RStudio for the assignment.  Can you please let me knwo is RNotebook / Markdown is another platform to use? Once the coding is done can I convert it to Markdown?

Comment: See here... https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within R studio, you can choose R markdown .
Navigate to File Option -> New File -> R Markdown

There are no changes in coding. All codes that you write in R would be as-is. Just with a flexibility that you can add comments and explain your code.
Make sure in .Rmd file, there are  {} clauses. don't make any changes to it while writing code.

You will observe below chunk in .Rmd file. Make sure you should not delete {} but you may write any heading within these brackets.Followed by these brackets, you can write your code.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````